# Mediator pattern example: chat

Tags: java, design-patterns, mediator

I read that chat is a sample of using of Mediator pattern. I wrote simple imitation of chat but I don't know how can I use mediator pattern in this situation.
As I understand all my object already have loose coupling and Server class is similar to Mediator.
Can someone show me using of Mediator pattern on my sample?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Server chatObserver = new Server();
        chatObserver.addObserver(new Client("User1", chatObserver));

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatObserver.addObserver(new Client("User2", chatObserver));
            }
        }, 5);
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatObserver.addObserver(new Client("User3", chatObserver));
            }
        }, 10);
    }

    static class Client extends Observable implements Observer {
        private String name;
        private List<Message> chatHistoryToDisplay; 
        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private Random random = new Random();

        public Client(final String name, Observer o) {
            this.name = name;
            addObserver(o);         
            chatHistoryToDisplay = new ArrayList<Message>(((Server) o).getChatHistory());
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int msg = random.nextInt(10);
                    String str = name + " writed " + msg;
                    System.out.println("\t"+str);
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(new Message(name,String.valueOf(msg)));
                }
            }, 0, 10000);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object msg) {
                chatHistoryToDisplay.add((Message) msg);
                System.out.println("----------- "+name+" screen -----------");
                for (int i=0;i<chatHistoryToDisplay.size();i++) {
                    Message m = chatHistoryToDisplay.get(i);
                    System.out.println(m.toString());
                }
        }
    }

    static class Server extends Observable implements Observer {
        private List<Message> chatHistory = new ArrayList<Message>();

        @Override
        public void update(Observable arg0, Object msg) {
            chatHistory.add((Message) msg);
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(msg);
        }

        public Collection<Message> getChatHistory(){
            return chatHistory;
        }
    }


    static class Message {
        private String author;
        private String message;

        public Message(String author, String message) {
            this.author = author;
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return author + ": " + message;
        }
    }
}
```

**CONSOLE:**

```
User1 writed 3
----------- User1 screen -----------
User1: 3
    User2 writed 9
----------- User2 screen -----------
User1: 3
User2: 9
----------- User1 screen -----------
User1: 3
User2: 9
    User3 writed 9
----------- User3 screen -----------
User1: 3
User2: 9
User3: 9
----------- User2 screen -----------
User1: 3
User2: 9
User3: 9
----------- User1 screen -----------
User1: 3
User2: 9
User3: 9
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, that understand your question correctly.

But I think, in this case, you don't actually need `mediator` pattern. If only there will be a lot of different objects that have to exchange some data. For example, ChatClient1 implementation, ChatClient2 implementation etc. They have to register themselves in `mediator`  and send commands to `mediator`. Mediator knows everything about other registered classes, but every `ChatClient` know nothing about others. Most of the times, this patter is using for UI. 
In your case, since you only have 1 type of ChatClient and one type of Server, `observer` is 
appropriate

Comment: I have 3 different client and one server through what clients are communicating to each other. I updates my post.Please see output.

Comment: They are the same, I'm talking about different implementation of interface, not about instances of the class

Comment: Ok,Sorry.Can you say how I need to change conditions of sample to use Mediator pattern?

Comment: For example, if you have got specific chatClient1 and chatClient2. When chatClient1 send message to mediator, mediator change color (for exmaple) of chatClient2. And vise versa. Both of the client knows nothing about each other. They simply exchange data with mediator and mediator do whole job. But in your case, observer simply broadcast messages to client. In your case obserever treat all clients as the same.